PiVPN does not connect to the internet
I installed PiVPN with Wireguard on my Raspberry Pi 4.
The installation was successful, and I can connect to the VPN, but I cannot access the Internet.
I tried the official FAQ and a lot of other fixes and it still does not work.
Here is the output from pivpn -d:
tee: /tmp/debug.log: Permission denied
::::        PiVPN debug      ::::
=============================================
::::        Latest commit        ::::
Branch: master
Commit: ececd4ed96b7e16493655131ae734b479aadd117
Author: 4s3ti
Date: Sat Apr 13 16:00:00 2024 +0200
Summary: build: Add automated release actions
=============================================
::::        Installation settings        ::::
PLAT=Debian
OSCN=bookworm
USING_UFW=0
IPv4dev=eth0
IPv6dev=eth0
dhcpReserv=1
IPv4addr=192.168.1.183/24
IPv4gw=192.168.1.1
install_user=vlad
install_home=/home/vlad
VPN=wireguard
pivpnPORT=51820
pivpnDNS1=208.67.222.222
pivpnDNS2=208.67.220.220
pivpnHOST=REDACTED
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITED=1
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITED=1
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=0
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=1
pivpnPROTO=udp
pivpnMTU=1420
pivpnDEV=wg0
pivpnNET=10.140.177.0
subnetClass=24
pivpnenableipv6=1
pivpnNETv6="fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::"
subnetClassv6=64
ALLOWED_IPS="0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0"
UNATTUPG=1
INSTALLED_PACKAGES=(unattended-upgrades)
=============================================
::::  Server configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = server_priv
Address = 10.140.177.1/24,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::a8c:b101/64
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = 51820
### begin fishyfish ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = fishyfish_pub
PresharedKey = fishyfish_psk
AllowedIPs = 10.140.177.2/32,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::a8c:b102/128
### end fishyfish ###
=============================================
::::  Client configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = fishyfish_priv
Address = 10.140.177.2/24,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::a8c:b102/64
DNS = 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub
PresharedKey = fishyfish_psk
Endpoint = REDACTED:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
=============================================
::::    Recursive list of files in   ::::
::::    /etc/wireguard shown below   ::::
/etc/wireguard:
configs
keys
wg0.conf

/etc/wireguard/configs:
clients.txt
fishyfish.conf

/etc/wireguard/keys:
fishyfish_priv
fishyfish_psk
fishyfish_pub
server_priv
server_pub
=============================================
::::        Self check       ::::
:: [OK] IP forwarding is enabled
:: [OK] Iptables MASQUERADE rule set
:: [OK] Iptables INPUT rule set
:: [OK] Iptables FORWARD rule set
:: [OK] WireGuard is running
:: [OK] WireGuard is enabled 
(it will automatically start on reboot)
:: [OK] WireGuard is listening on port 51820/udp
=============================================
:::: Having trouble connecting? Take a look at the FAQ:
:::: https://docs.pivpn.io/faq
=============================================
:::: WARNING: This script should have automatically masked sensitive       ::::
:::: information, however, still make sure that PrivateKey, PublicKey      ::::
:::: and PresharedKey are masked before reporting an issue. An example key ::::
:::: that you should NOT see in this log looks like this:                  ::::
:::: YIAoJVsdIeyvXfGGDDadHh6AxsMRymZTnnzZoAb9cxRe                          ::::
=============================================
::::        Debug complete       ::::
::: 
::: Debug output completed above.
::: Copy saved to /tmp/debug.log
::: 


The issue was the second Allowed IPs section had to be set to 0.0.0.0.
